# Horizontal Alignment in layout column

Tags: layout, extjs4, alignment

it's EXT JS 4.
A simple question,
how do i align items in layout column?

```
                    layout:'column',
                    border: false,
                    items:
                    [
                    {
                        columnWidth:.5,
                        xtype: 'label',
                        text: 'item 1'
                    },
                    {
                        columnWidth: .5,
                        xtype: 'label',
                        text: 'item 2'
                    }
                    ]
```

All I need is just align the 'item 1' to the right, and 'item 2' to the left. So, they'll be meet in the center.
Just using 'align:right' isn't work.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        layout: 'column',
        items: [{
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            xtype: 'label',
            text: 'item 1',
            style: 'text-align: right;'
        }, {
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            xtype: 'label',
            text: 'item 2'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: What about non-text elements? What if I want to align a grid panel?

Comment: What about if these are let say combobox? the same panel and layout

Answer (score 0):

Here is quote from Sencha docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Label

**NOTE**: in most cases it will be more appropriate to use the `fieldLabel` and associated config properties (`Ext.form.Labelable.labelAlign`, `Ext.form.Labelable.labelWidth`, etc.) in field components themselves, as that allows labels to be uniformly sized throughout the form. `Ext.form.Label` should only be used when your layout can not be achieved with the standard field layout.

Comment: What about other elements? What if I want to align a grid panel?

Comment: Center, right, wherever. OP asked how to align items in a column, and you gave an answer that only applies to Labels. Say I wanted to put a grid panel in a column and align it center; how would I do that?

Comment: OP asked about alignment, and I said that using labels is not a good idea. Create a new question with more detail description of what you are trying to achieve